# While moving arm, leg mesh messes up

Tags: animation, mesh

Newbie here. Just started using Blender. I did look through many questions, but most likely don't know what I should look for.
I watched tutorials, tried to fix vertex paint, vertex weight. starting to feel lost, can't seem to fix this! 
I would be so happy if someone could help me with this! Thanks!

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=46106

[image: leg_mesh]

Comment: Please consider using [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for sharing .blend files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not properly assigned *weights* to your *lowerarm*. Select this bone in *Pose Mode*, then select the character mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter the *Weight Paint Mode*. Set the *Weight* factor in a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) to *0.000*. Now select every single bone of the hand and see if there are weights assigned to the rest of the body and remove them (paint them, so they're blue).

***NOTE 1:*** I haven't removed all the weights- it's just an example.

***NOTE 2:*** The armature in my .giff is a bit off, since I'm using the older version of Blender than yours.
[image]