# Blender Armature Weight Painting - Bone does not move how he should

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I got a little problem. When i was trying to rig my character i weight painted with vertex groups. Now after i weight painted every single bone i got an issue on one hand. Its just one claw, all the others work as intended, but this one just doesn't move the way it should.

[image: Claw in its normal position]
[image: Claw when rotated]

The claw just doesn't want to move properly. When rotating it deforms itself in a weird position. When rotating the other claws (which are the same (mirrored and weight painted)) they just move perfectly.
Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that any other bone weights are not assigned to this one. Check every bone and if they share some weights with the one you pictured- just delete these weights. Example here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76715/while-moving-arm-leg-mesh-messes-up

Comment: Thanks you so much. It worked. I checked every bone and one was applied wrong. Now it works perfectly fine! :)

Answer (score 1):

Select your mesh and go into edit mode. Select single vertices and check *Vertex Weights* right in the properties shelf (see screenshot below). This way you can check for each vertex if it is influenced by an unwanted bone.

Another frequent error while rigging is if your mesh is mirrored. For modelling this is great, but when animating it's better to apply the modifier first.

[image: vertex weights]

Comment: I already applied the mirror modifier before starting to texture and rig. And i dont have that "Vertex Weights" Panel. the only thing i got is "Vertex Groups". But i already found my mistake. Had to check every single bone again. After selecting everything right, it worked. Still thanks for answering and helping me out! You guys are awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem working with v2.8, and I found that if you move your object out of its original hiearchy where it was "linked"/"parented" from the armature in the scene selection (in "View Layer" top left) into just the scene selection (in "View Layer" top left); then you have the option of reset to parent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  > *Set parent to > Armature Deform > With empty groups*.

This seemed to solve my problem. I believe what caused it was after I weight painted some vertex groups along with vertex selections assigned to vertex groups, I used *Decimate Modifier* to create less face/vertexes.

After that I realized my armature bones doesn't move the object anymore.