# Model won't move right with the rig

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, bones

I made an account just to make this post because I've googled it 50000 thousand times and **nothing**. Please keep in mind I'm new to blender, I've only been using it a few times and this is my first time rigging.

Okay so I'm trying to rig my character to move but it keeps doing this-

[image]

It looks fine at first and it does move, but its also moving things that it shouldn't. As soon As I move that left arm bone, the right one has a seizure. I have no idea what the problem could be. Any help would be appreciated :(

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76715/while-moving-arm-leg-mesh-messes-up

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91792/belly-deforming-when-moving-hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you used a mirror modifier for your mesh. Apply it before connecting it to your armature.

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe that fixed it...I spent like two hours online and looking at my mesh over and over...thank you kind sir

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the some vertex groups have been connected to the wrong bone in the armature.  Click on the bone that is causing problems then go into weight paint mode and look at what parts of the mesh are being influenced by that bone.

Comment: it could also be more complicated than this, if some bones depends on others... you have to check all involved bones...