# Rigging: Arm moves the pants even though it has no weight

Tags: rigging

So as the title says guys, i did a whole mesh and the clothes, imported my character as fbx and added armature and a rig, now i was setting weights and noticed that my model left arm is making the left pants side move even thought it has no weights.

[image]

I alredy assigned the weight in object mode to the pants as 0.
Dont know what else to do pls help
tnks in advance

Comment: Related or even a duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76715/while-moving-arm-leg-mesh-messes-up

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly figured out how to solve this, i hope this helps someone with the same problem.

[image]

what i did was i deleted all vertex groups that corresponded to the upper body inside the pants mesh, if i go to weight mode you can see that its purple because it has no vertex assigned as the arm in the pants mesh. somehow removing weight wasnt working so this was the only way i could solve that.